# What will be the confidence interval(for below question) for 99 percent confidence level [68 95 99 rule]

Tags: standard-deviation, standard-error, central-limit-theorem

Is the below solution correct....because  the probability of obtaining a sample which would have the mean height of 70 will fall under the intervals calculated using the mean+/- 3(SD) [99% Confidence level]

Sample problem: In general, the mean height of women is 65″ with a standard deviation of 3.5″. What is the probability of finding a random sample of 50 women with a mean height of 70″, assuming the heights are normally distributed?

z = (x – μ) / (σ / √n) = (70 – 65) / (3.5/√50) = 5 / 0.495 = 10.1

The key here is that we’re dealing with a sampling distribution of means, so we know we have to include the standard error in the formula. We also know that 99% of values fall within 3 standard deviations from the mean in a normal probability distribution (see 68 95 99.7 rule). Therefore, there’s less than 1% probability that any sample of women will have a mean height of 70″.

Comment: 1. What is the question? 2. You should improve a detail about the language. I guess that *"with a mean height of 70"* should be *"with a mean height of 70 or larger"*

Comment: I meant to clarify the last sentence.... about the probability of obtaining a sample which would have the mean height of 70..why is the probability of obtaining such a sample less than 1% since it will fall under the intervals calculated using the mean+/- 3(SD)

Comment: Did you calculate mean +/- 3(SD) and what is the result?

Comment: The interval will be 3*3.5+/- 65 which gives me 75.5/54.5...which means that 99.7 percent values (approx) will lie between 54.5 to 75.5.. please do correct me if my interpretation is wrong.

Comment: *"The key here is that we’re dealing with a sampling distribution of **means**"* The distribution of the means of samples has a different variance/sd than the population distribution.

Comment: So when you sample *a single person* then you will find 99.7% of the time the value within $$65 \pm 3 \times 3.5 = 65 \pm 10.5$$ but when you sample *a group* of 50 people then you will find the 99.7% of the time the value (of th mean) within $$65 \pm 3 \times \frac {3 } {\sqrt {50}} \approx 65 \pm 1.27$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. I don't think I have the option to mark it as an answer now.